# how I can get the data from the selected item in the listView from my database and view it on alertdialog?

Tags: android

I am having trouble with a ListView I created:

I have a food database but how I can get the data from the selected item in the listView from my database and view it on alertdialog?

I can view the data but when I click any of it, my application will stop working.

My code for this looks like:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listView;
    EditText editText;
    private DatabaseHelperList dbHelper;
    Adapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Item> arrayList = new ArrayList<Item>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //loadDatabase
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelperList(this);
        try {
            dbHelper.checkAndCopyDatabase();
            dbHelper.openDatabase();
        } catch (SQLException e) {

        }
        try {
            Cursor cursor = dbHelper.QueryData("select *from menulist");
            if (cursor != null) {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        Item item = new Item();
                        item.setId(cursor.getString(0));
                        item.setFood(cursor.getString(1));
                        item.setCalories(cursor.getString(2));
                        arrayList.add(item);
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }
        adapter = new Adapter(this, R.layout.custom_list_item, arrayList);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item);


        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id)
            {
                Cursor res = dbHelper.getAllData("select " + position + " from menulist");
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                while (res.moveToNext()) {
                    buffer.append("Weight: " + res.getString(1) + " kg \n");
                    buffer.append("BMI: " + res.getString(2) + "\n");
                }

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setCancelable(true);
                builder.setTitle("Confirmation:");
                builder.setMessage(res.getInt(res.getColumnIndex("id")));
                builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Intent startNewActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SQLiteDemoActivity.class);
                        startActivity(startNewActivity);
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            }
        }

        );

    }
}
```

This the log:

```
12-31 23:50:27.734 15775-15775/com.example.hidir.mnutrihealth E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.hidir.mnutrihealth, PID: 15775
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5 requested, with a size of 5
at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:426)
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getInt(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:68)
at com.example.hidir.mnutrihealth.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:76)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1162)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2953)
at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3708)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I already provide the log

Comment: The problem is when you use res to get the id outside of the while loop.  Why do you even have the while loop? The alert dialog should only show one item, correct?

Answer (score 0):

My first advice :

Create a class DAO for all the resquet into a database. Here, it will become unreadable if you add more than one call.

Second :

Are you sure that :

```
while (res.moveToNext()) {
     buffer.append("Weight: " + res.getString(1) + " kg \n");
     buffer.append("BMI: " + res.getString(2) + "\n");
```

}

Weight is a String and BMI a String too ?

If Weight is a int or a double, i think you have to use res.getInt(1) or res.getDouble(1). Check the real method, i don't remember is you have to specify the "column name"

Edit : I think i found the issue :

```
while (res.moveToNext()) {
                buffer.append("Weight: " + res.getString(1) + " kg \n");
                buffer.append("BMI: " + res.getString(2) + "\n");
            }

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setCancelable(true);
            builder.setTitle("Confirmation:");
            builder.setMessage(res.getInt(res.getColumnIndex("id")));
```

look at the last line. You would like to have the integer of something, but the cursor is now a the end of the list of item that were asking before.

You do :

A while loop for putting all the element on a StringBuffer, and when it finish, you ask a another time to access to a element that doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: I already change it, but my apps still stop working. Yes, I have no idea how to make it works

Comment: Can you print the value of the parameter on the setMessage method? On log or toast

Comment: I'm sorry, what did you mean?

Comment: Update the question with the changes you have made

Comment: @MoLab you can use the class Log from Android to display some information.  For example you can use Log.e("Debug", "the correct value is :"  + String.valueOf(your int)).  I think it will be easier to seen the content of your data.  After you can start the app in debug mod from your IDE and watch the content on time for a variable

Answer (score 0):

Answer is in the Log. It says, `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5 requested, with a size of 5` at `com.example.hidir.mnutrihealth.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:76)`.

The problem is here,

```
builder.setMessage(res.getInt(res.getColumnIndex("id")));
```

At the time when you call the method `res.getInt()`, size of cursor is 5 (means index values from 0 to 4) but it is pointing at index 5. That's why it is throwing `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException`.